# iterating through PictureBoxes in visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, picturebox

I'm programming in visual c++, and I have about 60 pictures (indexed p0...p63). I want to make a loop that goes through all the pictures and change their `ImageLocation` under some conditions.

I figured the `Tag` property and one of my attempts was like this:
I tagged my pictures from 0 to 63 and then tried the following:

```
for(int i=0; i<64; i++)
{
    PictureBox->Tag[i]->ImageLocation="possible-.gif";
}
```

It's not working... I get this error:

```
syntax error : missing ';' before '->'        line: 1514
syntax error : missing ';' before '->'        line: 1514
```

(twice, same line)

What's the right way of doing it?

Thank you!

***edit:***

OK now I have the pictures in an array. Is there a way to have a common rule for all of them? I want to make a click event for each and every one of the pictures. Is the only way setting a rule for each independently? Or can I set a rule for the array itself by saying something like:

```
if(Pictureboxes[i]_Clicked)
{
    Pictureboxes[i].something = "something else";
}
```

Comment: PictureBox is a class, not an object.  Tag is a property of type Object^, it is not an array.  It is so broken that it is impossible to guess what you had in mind.  Create an `array<PictureBox^>` perhaps.

Comment: @HansPassant i just wanna iterate through the pictureboxes in a for loop and do something on them (for instance change the `ImageLocation` property). How to use `array<PictureBox^>` ? i tried `array<PictureBox^> pics[64]` but it's not working...

Comment: @HansPassant ok i managed creating an array of pictureboxes. Now how do i present those pictures on the Form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to solve it. So I guess I'm gonna answer myself:

I made an array of PictureBoxes:

```
private: static array<System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^>^ pictures=(gcnew array<System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^>(64));
```

and filled it with the pictures:

```
pictures[0] = p0;
pictures[1] = p1;
pictures[2] = p2;
...
```

Then i clicked each of the pictures to create click_events.
In each event i typed this:

```
int place = (/*pic number*/);
IndexOf(pictures);
```

This code sends to a function named IndexOf the picture i clicked.
And here is IndexOf():

```
static System::Void IndexOf(int& place)
{
    int flag = 0;
    if(pictures[place]->ImageLocation == "possible-.bmp")
    {
        flag = 1;
        /*DO CODE*/
    }
    if(flag)
        /*OTHER CODE*/
}
```

Now i can do whatever code i want for pictures[i] at /*do code*/ above.